# Wix: Heat hidden files

Tags: file, wix, hidden, heat

I building an installer with visual studio. To include my files I use ***Heatdirectory*** in the wixproj-file.

Heat is including all the files (including the hidden files).
That's what I want.

But: When files get copied to the target-system all of them are marked as visible. Is there any option to keep their state? I could not find anything.

greez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I could not find a direct way to archive my goal I created an Custom Action and a (Pre-Build-)C#-Program.

Before building the Installer I search for hidden files and folders and create lists for them with a C#-Program.

After the files have been installed a custom actions marks these files and folders as hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the hidden attribute for a file when its copied by the installer. This makes the file hidden. Take a look at:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html (Look at the attribute Hidden)

However, I do not see an easy way to set this attribute on a file element when the file is being harvested. The only way I know of is to transform the generated output from heat as described at:

http://codedmi.com/questions/1552266/how-to-systematically-set-readonly-attribute-to-files-harvested-using-heat

Comment: So I'm afraid that there is no real solution because the harvested files are a mixture of visibile and invisible files and folders. But anyway thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe anyone else has another clue?